# Function modules to update table BSID (field: cession_kz)

Tags: abap, sap-erp

For a certain program I need to update table `BSID`. The field `cession_kz` needs to be updated. I've looked for many function modules but none of them fit my needs.

Does someone know a best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Without further information, updating a standard table column is prohibited by SAP, or at least you won't receive support for any related issue (i.e. you will pay for any assistance). So, if you really want to do it, then you can update it the way you want, no need of a function module.

Comment: `BSID` is not a table. It is a view.

Comment: @Jagger BSID is a table on R/3, it is a view on S/4 HANA

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai You're right. Sorry. Looks like this table is referenced from a million of places in coding. I would not touch it, really.

Answer (score 3):

BSID is a secondary index for BSEG customer items, so updating it directly will lead to database inconsistencies and any update **must** go via BSEG.

You can use a function module like `FI_ITEMS_MASS_CHANGE`. This FM updates BSEG by running a BDC for transaction FB02 (Change Document). When a relevant (customer) item is changed in BSEG, the corresponding BSID record is changed as well.

See example code below:

```
DATA: ls_bseg   TYPE bseg,
      lt_errdoc TYPE tpit_t_errdoc,
      lt_fname  TYPE tpit_t_fname,
      lt_buztab TYPE tpit_t_buztab.

* Field name to be changed
APPEND 'CESSION_KZ' TO lt_fname.

* New field value
ls_bseg-cession_kz = 'AB'.

* Selection of items to be changed
* Only select customer items to avoid problems in batch input
SELECT bukrs belnr gjahr buzei koart umskz bschl mwart mwskz
  FROM bseg
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_buztab
  WHERE belnr = '1400000000' AND
        bukrs = '1000' AND
        koart = 'D'. "Customers

CALL FUNCTION 'FI_ITEMS_MASS_CHANGE'
  EXPORTING
    s_bseg     = ls_bseg
  IMPORTING
    errtab     = lt_errdoc[]
  TABLES
    it_buztab  = lt_buztab
    it_fldtab  = lt_fname
  EXCEPTIONS
    bdc_errors = 1
    OTHERS     = 2.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
  WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
ENDIF.
```

Make sure you allow changes in maintenance view `V_TBAER` with transaction SM30 or through customizing:
*Financial Accounting → Financial Accounting Global Settings → Document → Line Item → Document Change Rules, Line Item*.

[image: Allowing changes to CESSION_KZ in customizing]

Note:
Pledging indicators should be defined for all company codes passed to the FM:

*Financial Accounting → Accouts Receivable and Accounts Payable → Customer Account → Master Data → Preperation for creating master data → Define Accounts Receivable Pledging Indicator.*

If not, the field will not be available for the batch input and the FM will result in an error.

[image: Defining Pledging Indicators]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but I get an error message saying bseg-cession_kz does not exist in screen SAPMF05L (program) 1301 (screen)

Comment: This can be caused by one of two things: either you didn't  allow changes for the field (see above) or the data supplied to the FM in parameter s_bseg contains invalid data (non-customer items or items that can not be changed). Can you double check the above?

Comment: Also, double check the company code and pledging indicator combo is defined: Financial Accounting → Accouts Receivable and Accounts Payable → Customer Account → Master Data → Preperation for creating master data → Define Accounts Receivable Pledging Indicator

Comment: I checked all of the things you asked me and these should be fine. I just don't understand what you mean by "invalid data (non-customer items or items that can not be changed)"?

Comment: If you open transaction FB02, select an item and click 'Additional Details', the pledging indicator should be changeable (see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/SYgnQJV.png)). This has to be the case for all items passed to the FM.