# Functionality not available: functional equivalent available

Tags: abap, hana

I'm migrating from `ECC` to `S/4HANA`. I'm trying to fix `ATC` message of a program.
But I'm stuck with the following error message:

> Functionality not available: functional equivalent available

It's relevant to foreign trade which is not supported in `S/4HANA`.

I have searched on Internet and it said `EIPO/EIKP` is not used. So What is the table which holds data of `EIPO/EIKP` in new system?

Comment: I think there is some kind of view for that stuff. I could swear that I saw a similar question somewhere here in the past. Will take some time however before I find it.

Comment: that's right. I see 2 questions like this, but it has no answer.

Comment: I found it but it actually was for the table BSID which was a transparent table on R/3 became however a DDL SQL View in S/4. Here is my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537296/function-modules-to-update-table-bsid-field-cession-kz#comment97780880_55537296) on that.

Comment: Have you checked the SAP note [2223144](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2223144/E) - S/4 HANA - Foreign Trade in SD/MM? According to it you have to perform some migration steps for foreign trade after switching to S/4 HANA.

Comment: @Jagger I suppose this should be an answer